# Translating screen coordinates to sprite coordinates in XNA

Tags: xna, screen, coordinates, sprite

I have a sprite object in XNA.
It has a size, position and rotation.
How to translate a point from the screen coordinates to the sprite coordinates ?
Thanks,
SW

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  The sprite's position is in screen coordinates, isn't it?

Comment: I want to translate a mouse click on the screen to X/Y of the sprite's image (if the click is inside the sprite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the following XNA picking sample useful:

http://creators.xna.com/en-us/sample/picking

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate the transform matrix for your sprite, invert that (so the transform now goes from world space -> local space) and transform the mouse position by the inverted matrix.

```
Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateScale(scale) * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(translation);

Matrix inverseTransform = Matrix.Invert(transform);
Vector3 transformedMousePosition = Vector3.Transform(mousePosition, inverseTransform);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to hit test against the sprite's original, unrotated bounding box. 
So given the 2D screen vector (x,y):

1. translate the 2D vector into local sprite space: (x,y) - (spritex,spritey)
2. apply inverse sprite rotation
3. perform hit testing against bounding box

The hit test can of course be made more accurate by taking into account the sprite shape.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be as simple as using the `Contains` method on `Rectangle`, the rectangle being the bounding box of your sprite.  I've implemented drag-and-drop this way in XNA; I believe `Contains` tests based on x and y being screen coordinates.

Comment: But does the bounding box take into account that the sprite is rotated?